# Mostrar imagen desde servidor //192.xxx.x.x/

Tags: javascript, html, c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una app que guarda imagenes en una ruta del servidor, ahora quiero mostrar las imagenes en una web asi:

```html
 <div><img id="foto" src="" alt="" width="50%" height="50%" /></div>
 
<script type="text/javascript">

  function showImage() {
        ruta = "//192.xxx.x.x/imgenesApp/xxx/1.jpg";      
        $("#foto").attr("src", ruta);
    }
    
</script>
```

Y el navegador me tira este mensaje:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://192.xxx.x.x:5000/ with MIME type text/html.

Mi duda es como solucionar esto, si esta bien dejarlo desde el javascript o se pudiera hacer desde el servidor, uso ASP.NET MVC con C#

Comment: Parece que el servidor está respondiendo con un Content-Type erróneo. Si es una imagen JPEG no debería ser `text/html`. A menos que la ruta esté mal y no se esté intentando acceder a una imagen JPEG sino a un documento HTML.

Comment: Hola si es una imagen jpg @HernánAlarcón

Comment: Además, el mensaje de error indica un "problema" de seguridad, probablemente estás haciendo la petición desde un dominio a otro dominio, lo que, para evitar ataques XSS principalmente, es bloqueado por la mayoría de navegadores, a menos que los headers sean los adecuados. Revisa que estés haciendo la petición desde el mismo dominio donde está la imagen, o si se puede modifica los headers CORS, para que esto no suceda

Comment: Y si la hiciera desde un dominio diferente como podría acceder a ella? @BenjamínGuzmán

Comment: Depende, si el servidor es tuyo, o tú puedes modificar su configuración, habría que cambiar los headers CORS, específicamente el header creo que es `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, revisa [este documento](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) para más información.
En caso de que el servidor no sea tuyo, o no lo puedas modificar, es imposible, a menos de que le indiques al navegador que descarte los headers de seguridad (lo cual no es muy buena idea)

Comment: Hay varias cosas a revisar como: permisos del servidor; si estás accediendo desde la misma red o de otra; si la IP del servidor es pública o local; si los puertos están abiertos tanto en el servidor como en firewall (software y hardware); etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la página la desplegarás en tu red local, verifica que tengas acceso a las imágenes desde tu navegador tecleando: file://192.xxx.x.x/imgenesApp/xxx/1.jpg, si puedes ver la imagen solo antepón file: a tu variable ruta:

```js
 function showImage() {
        ruta = "file://192.xxx.x.x/imgenesApp/xxx/1.jpg";      
        $("#foto").attr("src", ruta);
    }
```

Comment: Si pongo como tal la direccion en el navegador si me muestra la imagen, pero en la ruta del javascript me manda este mensaje en consola: Not allowed to load local resource:

Comment: Entiendo, la respuesta de @Benjamin Guzman te puede servir, aquí viene la causa y posibles soluciones en SO en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901523/file-url-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-in-the-internet-browser/35014520

Comment: Creo que las dos soluciones mas prácticas son 1. Copiar las imágenes a una subcarpeta de tu página web, 2. Instalar un webserver ligero en la ruta del servidor donde se encuentran las imágenes, esta solución con Python es muy sencilla, prueba con el siguiente link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901523/file-url-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-in-the-internet-browser#42294756

Answer (score -1):

Como el error de la consola es por `CORB`, el problema probablemente sea que el dominio (o en este caso el IP+puerto) de tu aplicación ASP es diferente al que colocaste en el URL: si estás ejecutando ASP desde Visual Studio (o desde el IIS) probablemente uses un puerto diferente al predeterminado.

Si la imagen está localizada en una carpeta dentro de tu aplicación ASP, lo más simple es que uses una *ruta relativa* para acceder a ella:

```
<div><img id="foto" src="" alt="" width="50%" height="50%" /></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function showImage() {
        ruta = "/imgenesApp/xxx/1.jpg";      
        $("#foto").attr("src", ruta);
    }
    
</script>
```